# Cordova iframe works but child to parent communication is blocked

Tags: javascript, cordova, ionic-framework, iframe, cross-domain

In my app, I am loading an iFrame into a modal; the source of the iFrame is my server.  The iframe content loads properly, but I am trying to get the parent window and the child window to talk to each other and am getting the following error:

`Blocked a frame with origin "https://api.myappdomain.com" from access a cross-origin frame`

In the controller, when the modal loads I am initiating the following:

```
  function iFrameMsg(d) {
    console.log(d.data) ;
  }
  $scope.modalOpen = function() {
    window.document.addEventListener('iframeMsg', iFrameMsg, false) ;
    $scope.iframeModal.show() ;
  }
```

And in the modal template:
`<iframe ng-src="https://myappdomain.com/content/index.html"></iframe>`

And in `index.html` on the server is the following scripts:

```
<script>
  function sendMsg(data) {
    var event = new CustomEvent('iframeMsg', { data: data }) ;
    window.parent.document.dispatchEvent(event) ;
  }    
</script>
```

And in the page a test button:
`<button onclick="sendMsg({'some': 'data value'});"> This is a button </button>`

Clicking the button to send a message back to the parent generates the error.  Is there something I need to add to my app, or the web page, to allow the communication to work between iframe server page and the app parent window?  Or will this technique not work at all?  If not, what would work then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [postMessage API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage) to send messages between your Cordova app and the web page in an iframe:

Cordova app:

```
// Listen for messages from child frames

const onFrameMessage = (event) => {
    const name = event.data[0],
    data = JSON.parse(event.data[1]);
};
window.addEventListener('message', onFrameMessage, false);


// Send message to child frame
const postMessageToiFrame = (name, data) => {
    iframe.contentWindow.postMessage([name, JSON.stringify(data)], "https://your.server.domain");
};
```

Webpage in iframe

```js
// Listen for messages from Cordova app
const onFrameMessage = (event) => {
    const data = event.data;
};
window.addEventListener('message', onFrameMessage, false);

// Send message to Cordova app
const postMessageToApp = (name, data) => {
    window.parent.postMessage([name, JSON.stringify(data)], "*");
}
```

Comment: Hey Dave!  Thanks for this.  I will be trying this out later and will post results.  I read multiple ways of doing this, many of which were using `window.parent.document.dispatchEvent` or `window.attachEvent` - I had read about the `postMessage`  too but it seemed postMessage was just a string whereas the others could pass native objects.  Is `postMessage` the only method that will work in this situation?

Comment: I use postMessage in this fashion in Cordova apps and it works fine. Yes it can only pass strings but you can stringify/unstringify to JSON and therefore pass pretty much anything.

Comment: Does the `window.addEventListener('message', ....)` and the `postMessage('message'.....)` have to be 'message'?  It worked when I used 'message', but changed it to `fromFrame` and it did not work.  Was  hoping to send messages from frame as `fromFrame` and from the parent as `fromParent` - but no worky.

Comment: ah, I guess it does, in the `event` object, I see `type: "message"`.  Thus the eventlistener is looking for an event type=message.